# Find the general solutions to the following differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question:** Find the general solutions to the following differential equations
>   $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {y}{x} $$ and $$  \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {-x}{y} $$
>   Draw the graph of those solutions and interpret what you see.

---

So the general solution is just integral multiplied by some constant, is it?
From that I will get $$ \int {\frac{dy}{dx}}=y $$ 
$$ \int {\frac {y}{x}}=y\ln(|x|)+C $$

*Is that true?*

---

And what should i do about graph of those solutions? Is that all possible answers on graph? Because y=CX in case of x is everything. In case of second you have circle equation and in case of K graph answer is everything.

Answer (score 1):

From
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}x$$
you have
$$\frac1{y}dy=\frac{1}{x}dx$$
so
$$\int\frac1{y}dy=\int\frac{1}{x}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

For your first one:
$$
\int \frac{dy}y = \int \frac{dx}x \\
\log y + C_1 = \log x + C_2 \\
ye^{C_1} = xe^{C_2} \\ y = e^{C_2-C_1}x\\
y = Kx
$$
For your second one:
$$
\int y\,dy = -\int x\,dx \\
\frac12 y^2 +C_1 = -\frac12 x^2 -C_2 \\
y = |\sqrt{k-x^2}|
$$
where only the $+$ sign of the square root works because when you take the square root of both sides yo need to do the same branch.

Comment: In the first case, you find $y=Kx$ with $K>0$ (since your $K$ is $e^{C_2-C_1}$) although the solutions are $y=Kx$ for every $K$, positive or negative or zero. In the second case, the reason why you add $|\ |$ to the final formula is unclear and your explanation on "only the + sign" is even more so, but anyway, you are missing the solutions $y=-\sqrt{c-x^2}$ with $c$ positive. Time to get more rigorous on the venerable subject called differential equations?

Answer (score 0):

you will get
$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{x}$$ and you will get $$y(x)=Cx$$

Comment: how have you jumped to that second line?

Comment: integrating both sides with respect to $x$